How to calculate ICC scores of aggregated items?
I have calculated the ICC2 single random raters of an item and the icc was .05. However, I would actually like to know the ICC of the aggregeted score across each about 300 of these items. Is there a way to calculate the ICC for aggregated items (NOT aggregated raters)? For instance, I wonder if that would be possible to do with the Spearman-Brown formula? But as far as I know this only works with the correlation coefficients - and correlation coefficients tend to overestimate interrater agreement, which is why I would like to use ICC instead.
Thanks!
